# API limitation while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a website that I'm scraping through using the code below. The information on the site is fed from an API and is from the ranges 10/2019 - 5/2020. The issue I have run into is that when I run the program and it exports the information to excel, it's only giving me the information up to 3/2020. I can't seem to find anything in the code that would stop this so not sure if it's something on the API end.

Here is the full URL: http://www.nhl.com/stats/skaters?aggregate=0&reportType=game&seasonFrom=20192020&seasonTo=20192020&dateFromSeason&gameType=2&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,goals,assists&page=0&pageSize=50

```
url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/skater/summary'

payload = {
    'isAggregate': 'false',
    'isGame': 'true',
    'start': 0,
    'limit': '50',
    'sort': '[{"property":"points","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"goals","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"assists","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"playerId","direction":"ASC"}]',
    'factCayenneExp': 'gamesPlayed>=0',
    'cayenneExp': 'seasonId<="20192020" and seasonId>="20192020" and gameTypeId=2',
}

for start in range(0, 100, 100):
    x = randint(3,10)

    sleep(x)

    print('loading:', start)

    payload['loading'] = start

    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

    data = response.json()

    df1 = df1.append(data['data'], ignore_index=True)

print(df1)

df1.to_excel('NHL Player Game Logs.xlsx', sheet_name='2019-2020')
```

Comment: you want to tag your post with relevant tags. Your problem isn't about parsing or creating `json`, so that tag has no reason to be here, it's not about _you_ trying to limit data responses so `limit` has no place here, `loops` is also not the thing you're asking about (because your loop itself is fine) and `scape` literally says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". And you were missing the most important tag: the language you're writing your code in. Next time remember that tags are there to help get the right eyes on your post. They're not just "keywords based on what you wrote".

Comment: As for the actual problem: there isn't one? The page you link to only shows "page 1 of 200" with the most recent date on it being March 2020, so the fact that you don't see anything more recent than that in your scrape result is exactly what one would expect based on the data we see on the page you're scraping.

Comment: `loading` isn't a key in `payload`. Try `payload['start'] = start`. By the way, you can set `limit` to `100`.

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping your loop once it gets to 100, so it only gets the first 50 rows. I would a) change the limit to 100 since that's the max allowed, b) loop until it's complete, and c) the payload is for the key `"start"`, not the key of `"loading"` (that's not in the payload). Also I don't think you need the time sleep:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/skater/summary'

payload = {
    'isAggregate': 'false',
    'isGame': 'true',
    'start': '0',
    'limit': '100',
    'sort': '[{"property":"points","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"goals","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"assists","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"playerId","direction":"ASC"}]',
    'factCayenneExp': 'gamesPlayed>=0',
    'cayenneExp': 'seasonId<="20192020" and seasonId>="20192020" and gameTypeId=2',
}

rows = []
start = 0
total = 10000
while True:
    #x = randint(3,10)
    #sleep(x)

    print('loading:', start)
    payload['start'] = start

    data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()['data']

    rows += data
    start += 100
    
    if len(rows) == total:
        print('Got all 10,000 records.')
        break
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df1.to_excel('NHL Player Game Logs.xlsx', sheet_name='2019-2020')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df1)
      assists  evGoals  evPoints  ...  skaterFullName teamAbbrev  timeOnIcePerGame
0           3        0         2  ...  Connor McDavid        EDM            1075.0
1           0        3         3  ...  Mika Zibanejad        NYR            1496.0
2           1        3         4  ...  Leon Draisaitl        EDM            1077.0
3           2        2         3  ...   Tony DeAngelo        NYR            1209.0
4           2        1         2  ...   Sebastian Aho        CAR             931.0
      ...      ...       ...  ...             ...        ...               ...
9995        1        0         0  ...      Torey Krug        BOS            1582.0
9996        1        0         0  ...      Torey Krug        BOS            1086.0
9997        1        0         1  ...      Torey Krug        BOS            1116.0
9998        1        0         0  ...      Torey Krug        BOS            1338.0
9999        1        0         0  ...      Torey Krug        BOS            1196.0

[10000 rows x 29 columns]
```